# difference between 'when' and 'if' in OpenModelica?

Tags: if-statement, modeling, modelica, openmodelica

I'm new to OpenModelica and I've a few questions regarding the code of 'BouncingBall.mo' which is distributed with the software as example code.

1) what's the difference between **'when'** and **'if'**?

2)what's the purpose of variable **'foo'** in the code?

3)in line(15) -  **"when {h <= 0.0 and v <= 0.0,impact}"**,, shouldn't the expression for **'when'** be enough as **"{h <= 0.0 and v <= 0.0}"** because this becomes **TRUE** when impact occurs, what's the purpose of **impact**(to me its redundant here) and what does the comma(**,**) before **impact** means?

```
model BouncingBall
  parameter Real e = 0.7 "coefficient of restitution";
  parameter Real g = 9.81 "gravity acceleration";
  Real h(start = 1) "height of ball";
  Real v "velocity of ball";
  Boolean flying(start = true) "true, if ball is flying";
  Boolean impact;
  Real v_new;
  Integer foo;
equation
  impact = h <= 0.0;
  foo = if impact then 1 else 2;
  der(v) = if flying then -g else 0;
  der(h) = v;
  when {h <= 0.0 and v <= 0.0,impact} then
      v_new = if edge(impact) then -e * pre(v) else 0;
    flying = v_new > 0;
    reinit(v, v_new);

  end when;
end BouncingBall;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, that's quite a few questions.  Let me attempt to answer them:

1. What is the difference between `when` and `if`.

   The questions inside a `when` clause are only "active" at the instant that the conditional expressions used in the `when` clause becomes active.  In contrast, equations inside an `if` statement are true as long as the conditional expression stays true.
2. What's the purpose of `foo`?

   Probably for visualization.  It has no clear impact on the model that I can see.
3. Why is `impact` listed in the `when` clause.

   One of the problems you have so-called [Zeno systems like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_system#Bouncing_ball) is that it will continue to bounce indefinitely with smaller and smaller intervals.  I suspect the `impact` flag here is meant to indicate when the system has stopped bouncing.  This is normally done by checking to make sure that the conditional expression `h<=0.0` actually becomes **false** at some point.  Because event detection includes numerical tolerancing, at some point the height of the bounces never gets outside of the tolerance range and you need to detect this or the ball never bounces again and just continues to fall. (it's hard to explain without actually running the simulation and seeing the effect).
4. What does the `,` do in the `when` clause.

   Consider the following: `when {a, b} then`.  The thing is, if you want to have a `when` clause trigger when either `a` or `b` become true, you might think you'll write it as `when a or b then`.  But that's not correct because that will only trigger when the **first** one becomes true.  To see this better, consider this code:

```
    a = time>1.0;
    b = time>2.0;
    when {a, b} then
      // Equation set 1
    end when;
    when a or b then
      // Equation set 2
    end when;
```

So equation set 1 will get executed **twice** here because it will get executed when `a` becomes true and then again when `b` becomes true.  But equation set 2 will only get executed **once** when `a` becomes true.  That's because the whole expression `a or b` only becomes true at one instant.

These are common points of confusion about `when`.  Hopefully these explanations help.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot, just one more clarification,,, Do equations inside a **when** become active for just **one iteration** only when expression after **when** get a transition from false to true?

Comment: Well, I don't recall the exact wording the specification uses but the basic ideas is that the equation remains active until the "event" is over.  Are you asking whether the equation might be evaluated more than once?  The answer is basically yes (there is a caveat when used in conjuction with `sample`).